# Database and Security

Tags: sql, security

If I am reading a sql query from an external file which is inside my local file system and then I am executing that query using prepared statements (All the calls are made from a java program) is that query still vulnerable to sql injection?

Question: The query that I am using from an external file is it vulnerable to SQL injection?

Flow : Java programs reads the local file which contains the query and executes that query using prepares statements

Comment: So the queries can be changed by others and then get executed in your program?

Comment: yes the queries can be changed by others if they can access that external file

Comment: A prepared statement is a fixed statement. People can input any query in your files. So you can't used a prepared statement since it is not prepared in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are an effective protection against injections. In this case reading from a file doesn't change anything. Your queries can be hardcoded or nested in a file.

**Nonetheless** the protection is effectless if people can change that external file.